# HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP. Only a type can be imported. com.mysql.jdbc.Driver resolves to a package

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" %>


<%
String user = request.getParameter("uname");    
String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login","root", "");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
//ResultSet rs;
int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into members(first_name, last_name, email, uname, pass, regdate) values ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + user + "','" + pwd + "', CURDATE())");
if (i > 0) {
    //session.setAttribute("userid", user);
    response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
   // out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='index.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
%>
```

I am using Tomcat. When I run this code, it gives me the following error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred
>   at line: 15 in the generated java file Only a type can be imported.
>   `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` resolves to a package Stacktrace:

Comment: Have you added mysql connector jar to the lib folder ?

Comment: Just a heads up, you should be using [`PreparedStatements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), because as it stands your application is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: ya i had added... jar Mysql jar to lib...... but not works....

Comment: Plz suggest me what to do